# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'query' was called on null. (Although it brings the items to the UI)

Tags: flutter, dart

### Problem Summarization

I've been on stack and seen this question a lot, I tried every solution I could find but it didn't work for me. I'm retrieving some data from my `sqflite` db and sometimes it fetches the results and some times it doesn't which appears to be pretty odd. I've read that you shouldn't call `init()` function in the constructor of the `Database`.

### It's said that this is this wrong

```dart
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class TaskDbProvider {
  Database db;
  
  TaskDbProvider(){
    init()
  }

  init() async {...}
}
```

How ever I've got a working example of the code above. (Although in my new approach it doesn't seem to work)

### Their Solution

Listen to a `Completer()` stream

```dart
class TaskDbProvider {
  Database db;
  var readyCompleter = Completer();
  Future get ready => readyCompleter.future;

  TaskDbProvider(){
    init().then((_) {
      // mark the provider ready when init completes
      readyCompleter.complete();
    });
  }
}
```

Although this triggers a **new chain of exceptions**, which i could provide if needed.

> [github link](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/124)

### The error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'query' was called on null.
E/flutter (29065): Receiver: null
E/flutter (29065): Tried calling: query("Task")
E/flutter (29065): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter (29065): #1      TaskDbProvider.fetchTaskList (package:oppo/resources/db_provider.dart:51:47)
```

### Line 51

```dart
Future<List<Task>> fetchTaskList() async{
    List<Map<String,dynamic>> list = await db.query('Task'); //line 51 (db is null?)

    return List.generate(list.length, (i) {
      return  Task.fromDb(list[i]);
    });
  }
```

### How I initialize the DB

Creating a BLoC (some extra functionality will be added later)

```dart
class BlocSpeech {

  final cache =  TaskDbProvider();
}
```

Make it available through the `InheritedWidget` (aka Provider)

```dart
class SpeechProvider extends InheritedWidget{

  final BlocSpeech bloc ;
  static BlocSpeech of(BuildContext context){
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(SpeechProvider) as SpeechProvider).bloc;
  }
  SpeechProvider({Key key, Widget child})
      : bloc = BlocSpeech(),
        super(key: key,child: child);
  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    // TODO: implement updateShouldNotify
    return true;
  }
  
}
```

### UI Widgets

Wrap the widget with the provider

```dart
 SpeechProvider(child: Work())
```

and Build the Widget:

```dart
class Work extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Work createState() => _Work();
}

class _Work extends State<Work> {
  List<Task> allTasks=[];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final SpeechBloc = SpeechProvider.of(context); //initialize the BLoC 
    final Future<List<Task>> future = SpeechBloc.cache.fetchTaskList(); //wait to fetch the items
    future.then((value) => allTasks=value); //assign them to local variable

    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: (allTasks.length),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
              child: _taskWidget(index,SpeechBloc));
        });
  }
```

> I will add any extra information if needed.

Answer (score -1):

"Called on null" generally means you jumped the gun on a future call.  Make sure that everything in the API that says "returns a future" or is "async" is in a method that returns a Future, and every call to a method that returns a Future is protected by an await.  There are some places you can leave some of that out when you understand more carefully, but that's a good first stab at it.

Comment: I wrapped the `ListView.Builder` with a StreamBuilder, the data is received and the they get null somehow. `snapshot.hasData` is `true` (fetches the items) and then it's `false`. Could it be that it's a render issue with the StatefulWidget?

Comment: Do you perhaps rebuild the Stream in something other than an initState?

Comment: I'm calling it inside the Widget's `build` method, that's where i have access to the `BuildContext` which is required for the `Provider`

Comment: Yeah, that's gonna blow up.  That's one of many reasons I shifted from Provider to Riverpod (heir-apparent to Provider).

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Although I have working examples of `Provider` that are used correctly. Probably I'm missing something out